# getServerSideProps not running

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, next.js

This is the code to my App Container

```
import { useEffect } from "react"
import axios from 'axios'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux"
import { setUserState } from '../slices/userSlice'
import {delay} from '../util/delay'

export default function AppContainer({pageProps, Component, data}) {

    const user = useSelector((state) => state.user.value)

    return (
        <>
            {console.log(data)}
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </>
    )
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    console.log("Hello")
  return {
    props: {
            data: "Hello"
        }
  }
}
```

App Container is in _app.js, so the component is being rendered every single time. However, getServerSideProps does not appear to be running. It does not console.log anything in both client and server, and when I console.log {data}, it says undefined, although getServerSideProps returns it as "Hello".

Comment: you are on _app.js. it does not run on _app.js. only on page files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

_app.js does not support Next.js [Data Fetching methods](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/overview) like getStaticProps or getServerSideProps. You must use the data fetching method inside your page apart from _app.js.

Comment: This is my <AppContainer /> component, not my _app.js. Should it still not work?

Comment: AppContainer is in _app.js file as you mentioned in the question so next.js data fetching methods work here